# Staging environments for every microservice?

Tags: architecture, microservices, devops, pipeline, environment

With a monolith there are usually several staging environments, for example development environment, test environment and production environment. Normally, these environments are physically separated from each other by their own servers. Gladly correct me if I'm wrong.

Does that mean that in the context of microservices, a separate set of staging environments and thus its own servers is required for each service? That sounds like a pretty big effort.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think practices vary widely, so it will be hard to get an objective answer. The important thing is to decide what makes sense for _your_ context (team, application, and business requirements). This includes asking the question of whether a microservices architecture is really appropriate at all.